# Apache CommonsExec async call preventing sync call

Tags: java, apache, maven, apache-commons-exec

I have two calls that I perform using CommonsExec - one is a standard synchronous call in which I call a batch file to compile a maven project, and the next is a asynchronous call also to a batch file that runs the compiled command line project.

The maven batch files look like

```
call mvn package
```

This is done twice, to compile and launch two programs.

This works fine the first time, but the second sync build call does not return for some reason, although the logged output shows the build completes successfully. The program then obviously is not launched.

I can also recreate this by doing a run, then a compile - it seems that so long as a asynchronous call is running, the synchronous call will not complete.

Can anyone help here?

Code for the above is

```
 private static final String LAUNCH_CLIENT_FORMAT = "\"%s\\start.bat\" http://localhost:%d" + ENDPOINT;
 private static final String COMPILE_FORMAT = "\"%s\\compile.bat\"";

 private static boolean compileAndLaunch(String aiDirectory, int port) {
   System.out.println("Compiling " + aiDirectory + " for port " + port);
   if (!run(String.format(COMPILE_FORMAT, aiDirectory), aiDirectory))
     return false;

   System.out.println("Done compiling " + aiDirectory + " for port " + port + ", launching...");
   if (!runAsync(String.format(LAUNCH_CLIENT_FORMAT, aiDirectory, port), aiDirectory))
     return false;

   return true;
 }

 private static boolean run(String command, String directory) {
   DefaultExecutor executor = getExecutor(directory);
   System.out.println("Running " + command);
   CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(command);
   try {
     executor.execute(commandLine);
   }
   catch (ExecuteException e) {
     System.out.println("Failed to execute " + command);
     return false;
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("IO Exception running " + command);
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }

 private static DefaultExecutor getExecutor(String directory) {
   ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   PumpStreamHandler streamHandler = new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream);
   DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();
   executor.setWorkingDirectory(new File(directory));
   executor.setStreamHandler(streamHandler);
   return executor;
 }

 private static boolean runAsync(String command, String directory) {

   CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(command);
   System.out.println("Running async " + command);
   DefaultExecutor executor = getExecutor(directory);
   DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
   try {
     executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
   }
   catch (ExecuteException e) {
     System.out.println("Failed to execute " + command);
     return false;
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("IO Exception running " + command);
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Comment: `but the second sync build call does not return` - do you mean async here?  Don't be shy to include your code, otherwise answers are just guessing at what you're doing.

Comment: Hey - I build synchronously and then trigger the program asynchronously. The second build doesn't finish although the output shows BUILD SUCCESSFUL. I'll add some code.

Comment: Do the two sets of batch files run in the same directory? Could it be  a deadlock in maven itself?  What happens if you run the four commands from the command line, in the same sequence.  I could not reproduce the problem when I replaced the builds with just an invocation of "sleep x".  Then a second synchronous command would run with no problems while the previous asynchronous command was still running.   Makes me think the deadlock is in the batch scripts, or in maven.

Comment: I did consider the batch file issue, but I copied the one project into a new folder to make sure they ran separately and it was fine. It's also fine if I kick them off manually in different threads.

Answer (score 2):

This is your callback:

```
DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
```

This is your asynchronous executor:

```
executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
```

But, in a asynchronous mode, right after calling `executor.execute()` the method will continue, but until something happens in another thread and `resultHandler.onProcessComplete()` or `resultHandler.onProcessFailed()` are called, you still don't know if the execution ended, and should not exit your runAsync() method.

I believe changing your method to something like this will work:

```
private static boolean runAsync(String command, String directory) {

   CommandLine commandLine = CommandLine.parse(command);
   System.out.println("Running async " + command);
   DefaultExecutor executor = getExecutor(directory);
   DefaultExecuteResultHandler resultHandler = new DefaultExecuteResultHandler();
   try {
     executor.execute(commandLine, resultHandler);
     resultHandler.waitFor();
     if(resultHandler.getException() != null){
       throw resultHandler.getException();
     }
   }
   catch (ExecuteException e) {
     System.out.println("Failed to execute " + command);
     return false;
   }
   catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println("IO Exception running " + command);
     return false;
   }
   return true;
 }
```

Because `resultHandler.waitFor()` will make the thread wait until the execution ends.

But this is the same as using the synchronous mode.
Only if both calls are asynchronous, you would win in performance, because they would run in parallel, and you would be waiting until both finish.

Comment: What is the meaning of DefaultExecuteResultHandler() if it has to block while waiting anyway? You have to always extend it?

Comment: There is no reason, but if there are many commands to execute, would be helpful. Would need to change parameter `command` to type `List<String>` or `String[]`. About the other question, you can also implement `ExecuteResultHandler`.